# How to store intermediate state in a Java stream processing

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following Java loop:

```java
for (final Long orderNumber : availableOrderIds) {
    final List<ReservationDetailResponse> reservations = tryToReserve(orderNumber);
    if (successful(reservations)) {
        return withReservationIdFrom(reservations);
    }
}
```

And methods:

```java
private boolean successful(final List<ReservationDetailResponse> reservations) {
    return !reservations.isEmpty();
}
```

```java
private Long withReservationIdFrom(final List<ReservationDetailResponse> reservations) {
    return reservations.get(0).getReservationId();
}
```

How do I convert it into a stream processing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map` for transformation, `filter` for conditions and `findFirst` you can do somethign like:

```
return availableOrderIds.stream()
        .map(this::tryToReserve)
        .filter(this::successful)
        .findFirst()
        .map(this::withReservationIdFrom)
        .orElse(0L); // assumed as default value
```

Additionally, provided the utilities, you can include them within the operations as well:

```
return availableOrderIds.stream()
        .map(this::tryToReserve)
        .filter(res -> !res.isEmpty())
        .findFirst()
        .map(res -> res.get(0).getReservationId())
        .orElse(0L);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of the following:

```
availableOrderIds.stream()
   .map(orderNumber -> tryToReserve(orderNumber))
   .filter(reservation -> successful(reservation))
   .map(reservations -> withReservationIdFrom(reservations))
   .findFirst()
   .get();
```